# Android Studio 3.3.2 No aparece el titulo de la aplicacion y las opciones en la parte inferior

Tags: android-studio

No entiendo porque no aparece el titulo de la aplicacion y las opciones de la parte inferior en el diseño.Estoy utilizando Empty Activity.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberia verse algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revertí tu edición y quité la leyenda de SOLUCIONADO, pues eso no es correcto, para dar la respuesta deberás ocupar el espacio de abajo "la zona de respuestas"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simplemente configuración, únicamente estas viendo el "Blueprint", ve a la opción "Select Design Surface" y **selecciona la opción "Design + Blueprint"**, de esta forma veras el diseño de tu layout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esta activado esa opcion. Y no se ve el titulo y las opciones en la parte inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado, solo tenia que escoger la opcion "Show Layout Decorations"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]